# implement an array of objects as attributes in one element in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component and I want to pass down an unknown array of objects (with unknown length) to it and display it as attributes in key and value format in the inner input tag.

```
<Input 
  type="text"
  label = {"length" + '(' + this.state.package_length_unit + ')'}
  placeholder = "length"
  defaultValue = {this.state.package_length ? this.state.package_length : ''}
  onInputChange = { this.onInputChange }
  attrs = {[{name: 'id',value: 'package_length'},{name: 'apikey',value: 'package_length'}]}
/>
```

inside the component I have something like this

```
<input 
  type = {props.type} 
  ref = {this.inputRef}
  className = {inputClassName}
  disabled = {props.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}
  defaultValue = {props.defaultValue ? props.defaultValue : ''}
  onChange = {props.onInputChange ? props.onInputChange : e => {}}
  onKeyUp = {this.handleTyping}
  placeholder = {
     props.placeholder ? props.placeholder : ''
  } 
  {...props.attrs} // ??
  // ********* here I want to have ==> 
  // id = 'package_length'
  // apikey = 'package_length'
  // ********* printed
 />
```

is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  ...props.attrs.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr.name] = curr.value;

    return prev;
  }, {})
}
```